# Why are comma-separated tags gluing?

Tags: meta-tags

I installed [metatags module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) and text list formatter. And I add in metatags keywords a string `[node:field_tags]`. And at my computer all is good, but on a server. It don't work.

It looks like in the keywords field when I open html code for example 'tag1tag2tag3tag4'. But on the server. it don't work It should be look like 'tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4' etc.

I can't fix it.
Who can know something or any idea??? How can I fix it?

Comment: Just to be sure, your code meta tags are displaying as "tag1tag2tag3" when they should be "tag1, tag2, tag3"?

Comment: @Jance yes. sorry for my English.

Comment: @Jance for example <meta name="keywords" content="microdataschemagoogle" /> but it should be microdata, schema, google